# Внешние ключи в стиле orm

Tags: java, hibernate

Как сделать внешние ключи в стиле `orm`? Пожалуйста, приведите подробные примеры.

Answer (score 0):

Внешние ключи это как правило связи One-One, One-Many

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table")
public class TableEntity {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "e1")
    private Entity1 e1;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Entity2> e2;

    @OneToOne
    private String e3;

    //getter and setter 
}
```

[Подробнее в документации Hibernate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations)

Comment: что это за joincolumn? список зачем использовать?

Comment: А вы документацию читали? Просто было бы неплохо, сначала ознакомится. OneToMany - означает что одному объекту TableEntity соответсвует много (список) объектов Entity2, JoiningColumn - показывает в каком стобце будет хранится id связаных объектов, аналогично @Column анотации.